# Finding COMMIT impossible in a Postgres Housekeeping Procedure

Tags: postgresql, commit, sql-delete

I have written a Housekeeping procedure in Postgres, with the simple logic...

DECLARE
BEGIN
LOOP (while there's data to process)
DELETE 1000 rows (configurable size)
COMMIT
END LOOP
END;
The problem is, the error I get is;

ERROR: invalid transaction termination
Where: PL/pgSQL function test.hskp(character varying,numeric,numeric) line 99 at COMMIT

Without the COMMIT it works fine.

is it just impossible to do this sort of BATCH approach, or is there a simple workaround?

Does anyone have an example?

Comment: You post half the code, how should we check the other half?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `COMMIT` inside a PostgreSQL function. You could use a procedure instead, but the easiest and recommended way is not to delete rows in batches, but all at once.

Comment: It's a procedure, but as you say, commit is impossible.

The problem without batching, is it takes too long, but maybe Postgres isn't scalable to large deletes (i.e. 20m deletes an hour sort of performance).  

Not sure what it's capabilities are, but they appear limiting, compared to say Oracle.

Comment: Then you should figure out where your `DELETE` performance problem lies, because that is not per se slow in PostgreSQL. Typical causes are triggers and foreign keys.