# I cannot COMMIT inside a procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, psql, pgadmin

This question has been asked before :

[Finding COMMIT impossible in a Postgres Housekeeping Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75146023)

[Postgresql invalid transaction termination when calling procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76962111)

...but none of the answers worked for me.

I have a loop inside my stored procedure. The loop contains **INSERTs**, which need to be **written to the output table at the end of each pass** of the loop.

- If I don't use COMMIT, I need to wait until the end of the stored procedure to have the results accessible.
- When I insert COMMIT (right before the "end loop"), I get the following error message :

```
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function [...] at COMMIT 

SQL state: 2D000
```

I tried the first example from the official documentation :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html

and I still get the same error message.

In fact, I made an even more minimal example :

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (a INTEGER);
CREATE PROCEDURE test_commit()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..9 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
            COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CALL test_commit();
```

Same error message :

```
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_commit() line 5 at COMMIT 

SQL state: 2D000
```

I am running the code from pgAdmin 4, and I tried switching "auto commit" on or off... same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine here with `psql` and the default autocommit mode. You must have started an explicit transaction ("disabled" autocommit mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CALL` that invokes a transaction-handling procedure cannot be wrapped in a transaction with the other statements, in any way. [The doc you linked](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html) actually mentions that, although without any details or [demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/o4fet_y4):

> Transaction control is only possible in `CALL` or `DO` invocations from the top level or nested `CALL` or `DO` invocations without any other intervening command.

Similar to how you need to run `VACUUM` separately because it refuses to run in a transaction, you have to run that `CALL` on its own:

1. **Select** just the line with `CALL test_commit();` and hit Execute/Refresh <kbd>F5</kbd>:
   [image: pgAdmin execute selection]
2. Move the `CALL test_commit();` to a separate Query Tool tab and execute it there.
   [image]
3. As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198667/i-cannot-commit-inside-a-procedure/78198983#comment137861629_78198667) by [@Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe), try switching from pgAdmin Query Tool to PSQL Tool and run it there instead.
   [image]

Both of the solutions in pgAdmin Query Tool will work regardless of `autocommit` `on`/`off` state. In psql, you'd have to explicitly open a transaction to switch it off.

Comment: So great to have all those options and a crystal clear explanation! I ended up using option 4) :) running it from the command line. My procedure is now running perfectly, giving me intermediate results; this really saved me.